# Is it possible to determine the iOS version last-update time?

Tags: ios

Haven't been able to find anything about this on the web yet. I know it's possible to determine the iOS version number. But what about *when* that version was installed?

Comment: There is no public API for this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do with this info?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I was thinking about different ways to manage users updating their iOS version, and reporting on that within an Enterprise environment